# Test divergent series using a comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Test series for convergence / divergence using a **comparison** test:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}$$

Now, If it would be $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2+1}{n^3-2}$$ then I could compare it as greater or equal to 1/n series which diverges, but since it is + 2 in the denominator then I am not sure what to do?

Comment: I believe the limits for the sum should be in terms of $n$, not $i$. Otherwise, the sum clearly diverges.

Comment: ahh, you're right :) sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n \ge 2$;

$\dfrac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}> \dfrac{n^2+1}{n^3+n}=$

$\dfrac{n^2+1}{n(n^2+1)}=\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Comparison test, harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: +1 The most simple way to prove divergence of the serie

Comment: Isham.Thanks. Was not so difficult:)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to compare starting at $1$. You have
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}\geq\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^3+n^3}=\frac12\,\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1n=\infty. 
$$

Comment: Note that we can also use $n^3+n$ for denominator and get a natural simplification without $\frac 12$ coefficient.

Comment: which kind of natural simplification are you referring to?

Comment: @DaniChe: from the first step, you have $$\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}\geq\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+n}=\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}}{\frac1n}=1,$$you have$$\frac{\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}}{\frac1n}\geqslant\frac12$$if $n$ is large enough. In other words,$$\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}\geqslant\frac1{2n}.$$Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}$ diverges, your series diverges too.

Answer (score 1):

You also have:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}\geq\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2+1}{2n^3}=\frac12 \left (\,\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1 {n^³} \right )$$
Harmonic serie is divergent.

Sum of a divergent series and a convergent series is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

As often, the simplest way is using *equivalents*, because of the following result:

> Let $\sum_n a_n, \sum_n b_n $ two series with positive terms, and suppose $a_n$ and $b_n$ are asymptotically equivalent. Then both series converge or both diverge.

Here, it is  particularly easy to apply, because a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term. Therefore
$$\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}\sim_\infty \frac{n^2}{n^3}=\frac 1n$$
and the latter is the *harmonic series*, which diverges.